# why is test function space $\mathcal{A}$ complete

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, distribution-theory

I am trying to find out, why the space $$\mathcal{A}:=\left\{\phi\in C_0(\mathbb{R}^{2d})|\;\|\phi\|_\mathcal{A}:=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}|(\mathcal{F}_p\phi)(x,y)|\;\mathrm dy<\infty\right\}$$ is a Banach space. $\mathcal{F}_p\phi$ denotes the partial Fourier transform defined by $$(\mathcal{F}_p\phi)(x,y):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-ip\cdot y}\phi(x,p)\;\mathrm dp,$$
while $C_0(\mathbb R^{2d})$ denotes the space of continuous functions which vanish at infinity. I don't know how to show the completeness. Does anyone have a hint or a reference?

Comment: If $\phi\in\mathcal{A}$ and we fix $x$. Does anyone know if the identity $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}(\phi(x,\cdot)))(p)=\phi(p)$ holds, where $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the normal, not the partial, Fourier transform? I know that the identity holds if $\phi\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\mathcal{F}(\phi)\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$. But here we only have $\mathcal{F}(\phi)\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$.